# How to pickle a custom loss function for lightgbm?

Tags: python, lightgbm

```
lgb_model = lgb.LGBMRegressor(max_depth=6, 
                          learning_rate = 0.05, 
                          num_leaves = 30,  
                          n_estimators = 500,
                          random_state=12,
                          silent=False
                         )

lgb_model.set_params(**{'objective': custom_asymmetric_objective})

lgb_pipeline = create_pipeline(lgb_model)

lgb_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

joblib.dump(lgb_pipeline, filename)
```

> PicklingError: Can't pickle .inner at 0x0000016552C52A60>: it's not found as lightgbm.sklearn._objective_function_wrapper..inner